# How to speed up this method?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working with a (highly optimized/adapted version of) CakePHP 2.3 and my application is running on VERY slow hardware (300MHz ARM) so I am still optimizing wherever I can. One method of the framework is called VERY often and not very fast (~0.5-1ms), but I can not think of a way to improve it (without changing the output) - in total I spend ~5% of the total time in this method:

```
function pluginSplit($name, $dotAppend = false, $plugin = null) {
    if (strpos($name, '.') !== false) {
        $parts = explode('.', $name, 2);
        if ($dotAppend) {
            $parts[0] .= '.';
        }
        return $parts;
    }
    return array($plugin, $name);
}
```

**Does anyone have an idea how to speed this up?**

According to the profiler strpos takes about 5% of the methods time and explode ~1%:
[image]
(Profiling is about 10-15 times slower then normal execution --> 8.8ms are ~0.5-1ms without the profiler)

Comment: Cake's resource requirements are usually not a good fit for a low-end hardware environment. Are you sure it is the right tool for the job?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: CakePHP was choosen for several reasons and I stripped down the framework already so it is "much faster", but some "slow methods" I just can't get rid of... (Did you downvote becaus of this? If not please exlaind the downvote so I can improve)

Comment: I did not downvote your question.

Comment: Just a suggestion: maybe you'll receive more answers in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than here, since you're looking to optimize that code.

Comment: @Nunser: Thanks for the tip - did not know about that (part of the)  site before...

Answer (score 1):

just a little improvement not to search the string 2 times:

```
function pluginSplit($name, $dotAppend = false, $plugin = null) {
  if (count($parts = explode('.', $name, 2)) === 2) {
    if ($dotAppend) {
      $parts[0] .= '.';
    }
    return $parts;
  }
  return array($plugin, $name);
}
```

Comment: That means explode is called every time - most of the time this method is called with a string that doesn't have a dot in it. As such this is unlikely to improve performance, more likely have a negative effect.

Comment: i don´t think so since 'strpos takes about 5% of the methods time and explode ~1%'.
if a dot is found you search for it 2 times (once with my solution).
if not dot is found you search one time (both versions).

Comment: Read _your_ version of this method, the input string is passed to explode every time. The strpos calls are to avoid calling explode unnecessarily - and the way this method is written is due to extensive profiling.