# How to speed up this method? Is is_int that slow?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working with a (highly optimized/adapted version of) CakePHP 2.3 and my application is running on VERY slow hardware (300MHz ARM) so I am still optimizing wherever I can. One method of the framework is called VERY often and not very fast (~1-5ms), but I can not think of a way to improve it (without changing the output) - in total I spend ~10% of the total time in this method:

```
public static function normalizeObjectArray($objects) {
    $normal = array();
    foreach ($objects as $i => $objectName) {
        $options = array();
        if (!is_int($i)) {
            $options = (array)$objectName;
            $objectName = $i;
        }
        list(, $name) = pluginSplit($objectName);
        $normal[$name] = array('class' => $objectName, 'settings' => $options);
    }
    return $normal;
}
```

**Does anyone have an idea how to speed this up?**

The profiler has the following output for one of the calls - I already asked how to improve `pluginSplit` [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938373/how-to-speed-up-this-method):
[image]
(Profiling is about 10-15 times slower then normal execution)

Is it the `is_int` that is that slow or where is that time "lost"?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: Not a duplicate - as mentioned in the text, I am asking about everything "except" the part already asked there...
I was thinking about asking it in one question, but I think it is better separated to not mix up answers.

Comment: Sorry, mistakenly voted for closing.

Comment: The issue at hand stays the same: The question is not any better then before. You are optimizing at the wrong end. Get better hardware or use a different tool. Cake needs good hardware and a 300Mhz CPU just doesnt cover it.
IF (and that is IF) you can find a way to make it faster here without losing any of the existing features, you can make a PR to the github repo. BUT it does not fix the other 1000 places you would need to modify to even getting close to a performance optimization. in short: lost time.

Comment: @mark: You could say my application is only "based on CakePHP", because I adapted it in many places to fit my needs, which worked great (much better then with other frameworks) and I am already able to run my app "pretty fast", but I would just like to "improve that last 10%" for these two methods...

Comment: If he manages to optimize the framework so it runs on a 300Mhz CPU, why stop him based on the official hardware requirements?

Comment: @Pekka웃 There are no official hardware requirements for CakePHP, of course restricted hardware is going to need some special attention. Personally if you manage to get reasonable performance out of a 300MHZ server/machine (with any software) hi5!

Comment: @Ad yeah, I agree! Just saying - that Cake isn't *supposed* to run on a machine like that doesn't make a Stack Overflow question to that effect invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Optimize by removing the method.

[normalizeObjectArray](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php#L322) is the method that converts arrays like this:

```
public $foo = array(
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three' => array('option' => 1, 'other' => 2)
);
```

into:

```
public $foo = array(
    'One' => array('className' => 'One', 'settings' => array()),
    'Two' => array('className' => 'Two', 'settings' => array()),
    'Three' => array('className' => 'Three', 'settings' => array('option' => 1, 'other' => 2))
);
```

If instead of trying to optimize this code, you refactor the code to not call it and ensure that wherever it's called the array is *already* in the format required (e.g. component, helper, behavior arrays), the logic is redundant and can simply be removed.

Answer (score 0):

First you can avoid the `list`. Instead, you can do:

```
$normal[pluginSplit($objectName)[1]] = ... ;
```

Secondly, I *think* (not sure) that `ctype_digit()` can improve performance a bit.

By the way, could you give an example of content of `$objects`? It sounds like a weird array...